# How to fill array with specific number of 1's and 0's in random locations?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, random, arduino

I have an array with 8 spots to fill and 4 ones and 4 zeros to fill it with, but want the locations to be random. I am a bit stumped on how to do this without it being to redundant. Is there a simple way to do this or will I have to fill the array with either a 1 or a zero randomly then  go through and check to see if it has the right number of both after the fact? My current code is along the lines of

```
void setup() {
  int one = 0;
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
    array[i] = random(0, 2);
    if (array[i] == 1){
      one++;
    }
    if(one >4){
      array[i] = 0;
      one--;
    }
  }
}
```

This mostly works but has the some obvious drawbacks so any pointers on a better way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: I would probably set the array to [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] and then shuffle it. Choose two elements randomly and swap them, several times.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I'll have to consider this for sure, its definitely a good option.

Comment: @Octopus 's suggestion can [be performed for you by `std::shuffle`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: This answer has changed slightly from the original

For an Arduino where resources are tight, this code would suffice, no need to link in extra libraries:

```
int a[8] = { 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1 };


void setup() {

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));

  for (int n=7;n>0;n--) {
    int r = random(n+1);
    int t = a[n];
    a[n] = a[r];
    a[r] = t;
  }

}
```

[This is exactly how the std::shuffle function is implemented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/), limited only by the effectiveness of the implementation of the builtin Arduino `random()` function

Comment: This "naive" implementation of shuffle does not generate the permutations with equal probability. The OP does not state that they want uniform distribution for different permutations, but this is normally implied. If so, this solution is not even remotely acceptable.

Comment: AnT is right.  This is a perfectly good idea, but the implementation is flawed.  Use `std::shuffle`, which I believe should be available even on an Arduino.

Comment: @Adrian, even if the number of swaps is increased? I'd like to see proof of that.

Comment: @Octopus:  I believe the second paragraph in this section covers it. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors

Comment: @Octopus: Increasing the number of iterations in "naive" shuffle (i.e. swap rand with rand `N` times) will, of course, level-out the distribution. However, in order to completely smooth it out for practical purposes you will need a lot more than 8 iterations. At the same time classic Knuth shuffle would require only 8 iterations to produce perfectly uniform distribution, which immediately makes the "naive" algorithm pointless.

Comment: @AnT, this code now matches the implementation of std::shuffle not that it's all that significant for the presumed use case.

Comment: @Octopus: I see that. My last comment is intended as an answer for your previous comment about "increasing the number of swaps".

Answer (score 3):

If you need to generate `m` random ones in an array of zeroes, you can simply iterate through the entire array and set the current element to 1 with the following probability `P`

```
           number of 1's that remains to be set
P = ----------------------------------------------------
    number of array elements that remains to be iterated
```

In your case you need to set 4 random 1's in an array of 8 elements

```
const unsigned N = 8, M = 4;
int array[N];

for (unsigned i = 0, m = M; i < N; ++i)
  if (rand() % (N - i) < m)
  {
    array[i] = 1;
    --m;
  }
  else
    array[i] = 0;
```

This generates the random array in one pass - no need to post-shuffle anything.

P.S. In order to make the decision with the above probability `P` I used the oft-criticized `rand() % (N - i) < m` method. This is besides the point, of course. You can use any other method of your choice.